# calculate the number of PDF pages generated from a HTML document

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

So basically I am creating PDF documents in my app using wkhtmltopdf.
My app is a builder app, the user adds and removes some elements and then presses a button to send the data to the server to generate to PDF doc.

I want to show the user the number of pages of the PDF that is going to be generated. Is it possible somehow calculate that based on the document height and font size's?

Comment: Depending on what technology you use to generate the PDF, and how complex your builder app is, this is going to be extremely hard to get right. Easy enough to get almost right, but in the generic case almost impossible to get right 100% of the cases. The most accurate way would be to generate the PDF and just try to be honest. I have some experience with generic HTML to PDF technology based on Webkit, and that product uses a two-pass approach to generate content like page numbers (page 1 of X) exactly because of this problem.